# Edit text in textarea angularJs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am editing text in textarea in admin View and want to display it via  angular service on User view, so text displayed as single row. How can I display it in multiple rows i.e., in same format that I entered in textarea?
*Its my textarea and btn on admin view*

```
 <textarea name="" id="textAreaAbout" cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="aboutAdmin.about"></textarea>
 <button type="button" class="btn-primary" ng-click="aboutAdmin.saveAboutBtn(aboutAdmin.about)">Save</button>
```

*service*

```
app.factory('global', function(){

    let _items = [
        'Hi, my name is Pavlo Lapan and I am front-end developer from Ukraine.',
        'I have got more than 1 years of experience in web development. I think my strong points are dedication, punctuality and easy in communication',
        'Right now I am on the third year of studying at Software Engineering specialization in Lviv National University, in Ukraine.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto aspernatur, distinctio doloribus error et maxime tempore? Ducimus, exercitationem sed.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto aspernatur, distinctio doloribus error et maxime tempore? Ducimus, exercitationem sed.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto aspernatur, distinctio doloribus error et maxime tempore? Ducimus, exercitationem sed.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto aspernatur, distinctio doloribus error et maxime tempore? Ducimus, exercitationem sed.'
    ];

    let _itemId = 1;

    return {
        getItems: function(){
            return _items;
        },
        getItemId: function(){
            return _itemId;
        },
        setItemId: function(itemId){
            if(itemId<_itemId) alert('error')
            else _itemId = itemId;
        },
        setItems: function (items) {
            _items = items;
        }
    }
})
```

*controller*

```
app.controller('aboutAdminCtrl', function(global){
    let vm = this;
    vm.about = global.getItems();

    vm.saveAboutBtn = function (text) {
        console.log(vm.about);
        vm.about = text;
        console.log(vm.about);
        global.setItems(vm.about);
    }
})
```

*user view*

```
<p ng-repeat="text in about.about track by $index">{{text}}</p>
```

*user Ctrl*

```
app.controller('aboutCtrl', function(global){
    let vm = this;
    vm.about =[];
    vm.about = global.getItems();
})
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you can have only problems with conversions. To convert from textarea model into your _items, try to split string by `\n`. If my understanding is wrong could you please clarify?

Comment: in user view when you click save button text displayed per one letter - like 
P\n
A \n
V\n

Comment: As I thought! ;) This symptom confirms my hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was using string: 'line1\n;line2\netc...' instead of ['line1', 'line2', 'etc...']

In Javascript, string is technically an array of single characters ;) ['l', 'i', 'n', 'e', '1', '\n', ...]. So you was simply iterating over single characters using ng-repeat.

To solve the problem you have to add some conversion:

```
app.controller('aboutAdminCtrl', function(global){
    let vm = this;
    vm.about = global.getItems();

    vm.saveAboutBtn = function (text) {
        const separateLines = text.split('\n');
        global.setItems(separateLines);
        vm.about = global.getItems(); //I guess that list of separate lines is proper format here
        console.log(vm.about);
    }
})
```

**EDIT**

I forgot important thing. You need separate field for model for `textarea` because `textarea` itself needs pure text: 'line\nline2\n...', and `ng-repeat` operates on array of lines. The best way to solve problem would be to move conversions into additional getter and setter of `global` service.

Comment: yes) it works well) and maybe you know how to separate this text to good view 
like 5 words in a row

Comment: If you wish for a good view maybe apply some markup language? I don't suggest parsing it manually. Use some library/framework instead. It should be plenty of it nowadays.